# Passing a URL string to a Javascript function

Tags: php, javascript

I need to pass a URL to a JavaScript function something like the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

var xmlhttp='';   
function ajax()
{
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
         xmlhttp = new ActivexObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
}     

function someFunction(orders_per_page, url)
{
     ajax();
     var val=document.getElementById("txt_order_amount").value; 
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
     {
          if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
          {                
               document.getElementById("list").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
     }

     xmlhttp.open("GET",url, true);
     xmlhttp.send();        
}
</script>

<select 
    id="cmb_page" name="cmb_page" 
    onchange="someFunction(this.value, "reports/OrderAmount.php?val="+val+"&orders_per_page="+orders_per_page+"&pageNo="+getSelectedPage();">

    <option value="1">Some Value</option>
</select>
```

I need to pass a URL string as mentioned on the `onchange` even of the `<select><option></option></select>` element. Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible. And I can't find any error in your function at first sight. What's the problem with it? Make sure your `val` and `orders_per_page` vars are defined, as well as `getSelectedPage()` returning a valid value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
onchange="someFunction(this.value, 'reports/OrderAmount.php?val='+val+'&orders_per_page='+orders_per_page+'&pageNo='+getSelectedPage());"
```

Note: I have replaced double quotes with single quotes

Comment: Already tried that. It's not working. Internet Explorer only reports "*Syntax error.*"

Comment: it works if those variables were set in the right place - i just tested it. Check my comments below

Answer (score 1):

You can also break your code a little bit to prevent as much tag soup.

I assume your `val` var is defined and in the global scope:

```
onchange="someFunction(this.value)"

function someFunction(orders_per_page) {
    var url = "reports/OrderAmount.php?val="+val+"&orders_per_page="+orders_per_page+"&pageNo="+getSelectedPage();
    ajax(); // ... rest of your function
```

Make sure `getSelectedPage()` is returning a `string`, or a number which can be parsed as string.

Comment: No I need to pass this URL from this function only `onchange="someFunction(this.value)"` as one more parameter. What you mentioned is working fine.

Comment: In my code above, I'm defining the `url` inside the function itself. I have no idea where the `val` var or `getSelectedPage()` function are or what values they have or return, but my example above will do basically the same as your `url` defined inside the HTML. Give it a try and check if there will be a syntax error still :)

Comment: Or do you mean, you have another function call passing a completely different `url`? I can review the code if that's case, but if @tunmise fasipe's answer didn't solve your problem, there's more likely something else breaking your code.

Comment: I just tested the code now and it worked in chrome and IE9. May be "val" and "orders_per_page" and "getSelectedPage()" function were not declared. I declared them and they worked. For val and orders_per_page to work, you have to declare them global

Comment: Well, I alternatively changed the code to pass only the page name that I need to change through this function `onchange="someFunction(this.value, 'OrderAmount.php')"` and concatenated it to the URL. Not the approach I was looking for but somehow it works.

Comment: Glad your code worked, your function looks much cleaner now as well.